# How can I derive k or x in s = (m + r*x)/k, when x is unknown constant and k is unknown variable?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

It's been a while since algebra class and I've exhausted by google-foo here. How do I get x and k on a side by themselves AND only on one side? I get to a certain point and it feels like I'm missing some important rule.

$$s = \frac{(m + rx)}{k}$$

First step could be multiply both sides by k:

$$sk = m + rx$$

then divide both sides by x, but it doesn't seem to get rid of x on the right side because of m.

$$\frac{sk}{x} = \frac{m}{x} + r$$

What I'm looking for is something to the effect of:

$$xk = m,r,s$$

**Edited**

What I'm really trying to do is derive a value for *x* or *k* when *m, r, and s* are known, x is an unknown constant, and k is an unknown variable.

Given:
$$s = \frac{(m + rx)}{k}$$

I have a series of values:

$$(m1, r1, s1) = (100, 50, 480)$$ 
$$(m2, r2, s2) = (110, 60, 340)$$ 
$$(m3, r3, s3) = (35, 90, 3701)$$

```
x is an unknown constant.

k is a different unknown random number in each set
```

$$k1 = 13$$ 
$$k2 = 22$$ 
$$k3 = 3$$

To derive x, I was thinking that if I could know a product of x*k, something like:
$$xk = m,r,s$$

Which in this example yields:

$$xk1 = 1599$$ 
$$xk2 = 2706$$ 
$$xk3 = 369$$

From that I can determine the greatest common divisor which produces x:

$$x = 123$$

Any ideas about how I can approach this?

Comment: SInce you only have one relation, you can get $x(s,m,r,k)$ or $k(s,m,r,x)$ but no more.

Comment: As @ClaudeLeibovici says, can't be done. If you edit the question to tell us where the problem comes from and why you need to know perhaps we can suggest another strategy.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @EthanBolker, thanks! I expanded my question to include my goal. Thanks for any insight here.

Comment: That edit really helps. If you substitute the numerical values you have into the relation you will have three linear equations in two unknowns. Those equations may have no solutions, or a unique solution, or multiple solutions. Standard linear algebra techniques will tell you which. Solutions may or may not be integers.